# How to fix 'stack around variable was corrupted.' Variables not changing to assigned value after initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mergesort

So my merge sort code worked and then I started getting some errors when I tried to get the run time. Now, I am getting 'array was corrupted' and I think it is because after initialization of 'left_bound' and 'right_bound' the values will not change even though I am pretty sure I am assigning them correctly. So they are some huge negative number which is out of the bounds of the array causing it to be corrupted (I think).

I have tried assigning and initializing in every possible way I can find on google.

```
    void merge(int arr[], int low_idx, int partition, int high_idx) {
    int i, j, k, right_bound;
    int left_bound (partition - low_idx + 1); 
    right_bound = (high_idx - partition);
    //temporary arrays
    int* left_of_partition = NULL;
    int* right_of_partition = NULL;
    left_of_partition = new int[left_bound];
    right_of_partition = new int[right_bound];

    for (i = 0; i < left_bound; i++) {
        left_of_partition[i] = arr[i + low_idx];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < right_bound; j++) {
        right_of_partition[j] = arr[partition + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 1;
    while (i < left_bound && j < right_bound) {
        if (left_of_partition[i] < right_of_partition[j]) {
            arr[k] = left_of_partition[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = right_of_partition[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < left_bound) {
        arr[k] = left_of_partition[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < right_bound) {
        arr[k] = right_of_partition[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    delete[] left_of_partition;
    delete[] right_of_partition;
    left_of_partition = NULL;
    right_of_partition = NULL;

}

void mergesort(int arr[], int low_idx, int high_idx)
{
    if (high_idx > low_idx) {
        int partition = (low_idx + high_idx) / 2;
        mergesort(arr, low_idx, partition);
        mergesort(arr, partition + 1, high_idx);
        merge(arr, low_idx, partition, high_idx);
    }

}
int main()
{
    int v2[] = { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
    int max_idx = sizeof(v2) - 1;
    mergesort(v2, 0, max_idx);
}
```

Comment: 1) The problem is undefined behavior somewhere in your code. Without [mcve] - hard to tell where. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: are you checking for lower & upper bound  to be 1 or greater?

Comment: I have stepped through with a debugger a billion times the left_bound and right_bound variables are not changing from the value at initialization (some giant neg. number) to what I set them to even though all of the variables are defined with integers >= 0 and < size of array

Comment: @RebeccaBrent "_I have stepped through with a debugger a billion times the left_bound and right_bound variables are not changing from the value at initialization (some giant neg. number)_" 1) Did you investigate, **at each step**, the values of all variables, to see that they matched your expectations? And did you took note, of the moment they didn't? 2) The values of those variables, depend on the values, of other variables, that are not shown to us. Once again, please provide [mcve]. If they are, indeed negative, then those `new` statements are undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I looked at each step. I know how to use the debugger, I am not new to coding just new to stack overflow and c++.

Comment: Also, they are negative. That is exactly my problem but when I assign left_bound and right_bound they just have the dummy value of -9000000 and do not change to the value I am assigning them to even if I try constants. left_bound = 5; does not work. It just stays as the value it got at initialization.

Comment: @RebeccaBrent 1) "_I looked at each step. I know how to use the debugger_" If you did look at the variables, at each step, and know how to use the debugger, what was the value of `max_idx`? Since [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't do what you think it does. Any other behavior, is explained by the undefined behavior, caused by you indexing the array out of bounds.

Comment: To avoid such problems in the future use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)   instead of C-style arrays and [avoid new and delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). Use `std::vector::at`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(v2)` returns the memory size of the complete array (`= 10 * 4 = 40`). You have to use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(element)`to get the correct number. 
With a size = 40 your code is writing into memory behind that local (stack array) of 10 elements which corrupts the stack:

```
int main()
{
  int v2[] = { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
  int max_idx = sizeof(v2) / sizeof(int) - 1; // divide by sizeof(int)
  mergesort(v2, 0, max_idx);
  return 0;
}
```